# removing marker google map doesn't work API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

i'm currently working on google map and i'm going through a problem i can't solve myself.
i've been following some docs and answer on stackOverflow but i can't get it work properly ..

i have one and only one marker on my map, all i want to do is removing it to put a new one each time the dragent event is firing ...

When i'm debugging the code, it seems like my marker ain't deleted from the map or i don't .. i don't really understand the behavior ..

So here is the code :

my google map instance :

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
zoom: levelZoom,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.6548670, 3,1888100),
});
```

the manip :

```
var markerHome = null;

function deleteCurrentMarkers(){
if (markerHome != null){
    console.log("set markerHome to null");
    markerHome.setMap(null);
    markerHome = null;
}
}

function setRelayMap(dataSource, currentCoords, myFilterObject){
var i;
var lt = currentCoords.lat;
var lg = currentCoords.lng;


deleteCurrentMarkers();
markerHome = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(lt, lg),         map: map, icon: "icoMaps/initPos.png"});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
    var centerObj = map.getCenter();
    var newObj = {"lat": centerObj.lat(), "lng": centerObj.lng()};
    console.log("in dragend");
    getDataFromServer(newObj, myFilterObject);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    levelZoom = map.getZoom();
});
    }
```

can you see anything that could cause my problem ?

thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

When you call deleteCurrentMarkers method your markerHome variable is null. So the code doesn goes into if statement.

```
function deleteCurrentMarkers(){
if (markerHome != null){ //markerHome is null here!!!
    console.log("set markerHome to null");
    markerHome.setMap(null);
    markerHome = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but it is just the very first time, after the first marker installation, it is not supposed to be null, when you see the map the first time, there is a marker but no "set markerHome to null", but if i drag the map, markerHome is not null anymore... the function getDataFromServer get me the new lat and lng of the futur marker and then call setRelayMap again ...

Comment: Ok you are right. When are you calling setRelayMap function? According to your code, your marker doesnt care about map dragend event..

Comment: Sorry I see your comment edit now. Everything is ok on your screnerio. Did you watch console? Is delete function works?

Comment: Yeah i got the answer, my drag end event was fired several time at the same moment, a little timeout to avoid this behavior and everything worked perfectly .. thank you for you time Mehmet !

Answer (score 1):

I think `deleteCurrentMarkers()` will never be fired 2nd time cose you fire it only when `setRelayMap()` is fired. You should fire in "dragend" callback or in `getDataFromServer()`